# Problem with stopping Python window from closing

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

This is a small and very basic program/game. I am having trouble with the unexpected close of the Python terminal before the end of the code. But within the PyCharm IDE, when I run the code, the program runs fine and only ends when all of the code is executed and the input has been entered from the user. I don't know if it's because of the logic behind my programming, I am still very new at this and so I am aware that might be the problem.

I have tried using an input to prevent the window from closing.

`input("\nPress any key to exit... ")`

Like I have previously said, that seems to work in the IDE but not when running the program directly from the .py file

I **do not** want to pass by CMD or a batch file to run the program. I want the users to be able to run the game by simply pressing on the Pycharm file and running it trough it's respective console.

***Here is the code :***

```
import random
inputCounter = 0
lineNumber = 0
playerNumber = 0
randomNumber = random.randint(1, 100)
win = 0
playerName = input("Please enter your name: ")


while playerNumber is not randomNumber:
    playerNumber = int(input("Please guess a whole number from 1 to 100: "))
    inputCounter += 1
    if playerNumber < randomNumber:
        print("The number you have entered is LOWER than the generated number, please try again!")
        continue
    elif playerNumber > randomNumber:
        print("The number you have entered is HIGHER than the generated number, please try again!")
print()

if inputCounter > 1:
    print("You won with {0} guesses".format(inputCounter))
else:
    print("CONGRATS! You won with 1 guess!!")


scoreList = open("Score.txt", "a",)
scoreList.write("Player: {0} | Guesses: {1}\n".format(playerName, inputCounter,))
scoreList = open("Score.txt", "r")
print("\nHere is your score list :")
for line in scoreList:
    line = line.strip()
    find = line.find(playerName)
    if find >0:
        lineNumber += 1
        score = line[line.rfind(" ")+1:]
        print("Attempt #{0} | Score: {1}".format(lineNumber, score))
input("\nPress any key to exit... ")


scoreList.close()
```

PyCharm IDE runs the program until the ends (Print's the number of attempts and the player's scoreboard and then waits for the user's input to exit). 
**This is what I want to happen when running the app through Python's console.**

**EDIT :** 
This is also the case if I run the program through CMD via a batch file, I would still like to avoid that if possible

As of now, Python's console closes as soon as the user guesses the corrects number, not waiting for the user's input to exit. I am guessing that the program does still print the number of attempts and the player's scoreboard but the console closes way too quickly for the user to see those lines.

Comment: A possible explanation could be an error being thrown in the code where you read/write the scores. It's not with the opening of the file, since you are using append mode first and ensuring it always exists. I tried with a file containing only the `input` line and it waits even on opening via double click. Try adding some print statements (and `sleep` to give you time to read them) to find out which line may be failing.

Comment: Also, this is a long shot, but go under the 'Open With' menu and make sure it is using Python 3 (on launching with double click). I had Python 2 also installed, and it tried to open with that first. Though I admit no part of this jumps out as Python 2 incompatible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I added a `try-except` block around the entire score reading code, and I managed to grab an error. However, I think that *might* be specific to my own Python 3 installation, so you should use the same approach and see what your problem might be.

In my case, Python 2 is installed in `C:\` while Python 3 is in (for some reason) `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36`. When I run your code, it used to open using Python2 by default and that worked fine. It created and read from `Scores.txt` as expected.

When I manually made it use Python3 though, it always crashed with `[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'Score.txt'`, which is a permissions issue. You probably see why I think this is due to my install location now.

Anyway, you can use the code below to hopefully print the error message. Once you have that, it should be easy to fix whatever the bug may be. The rest of the code (including the `input` call after this) should remain the same.

```
try:
    scoreList = open("Score.txt", "a",)
    scoreList.write("Player: {0} | Guesses: {1}\n".format(playerName, inputCounter,))
    scoreList = open("Score.txt", "r")
    print("\nHere is your score list :")
    for line in scoreList:
        line = line.strip()
        find = line.find(playerName)
        if find >0:
            lineNumber += 1
            score = line[line.rfind(" ")+1:]
            print("Attempt #{0} | Score: {1}".format(lineNumber, score))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```